# Which IP should I provide if I am on a DHCP network?

Tags: ip, dhcp-server

I'm currently working with a company and I can only access their web services if I send them my IP number.  My computer is currently on a DHCP network.  How do I find out which IP I have to give them?  I'm running OS X 10.6 with an Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Mac you are using is at home, then you will need to provide your workplace with your external IP address. This is provided by your ISP and is how your computer is known to the world wide web. You can find it by going to www.whatsmyip.org

Hope this helps!

DHCP is simply the automated method which your home router uses to assign unique IP addresses to each device connected to your local network.

Comment: horatio is correct in that your external IP address may not be static, and may change.

Comment: If you are not on a static WAN address, you may be able to set up dyndns (dyndns.org or similar services) within your internet connection device (router) or computer and provide the company with a name they can resolve back to your current WAN IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You would provide them with the WAN address of the dialup/cable/dsl/fios modem. You would need to log into the modem and look this up. Unless you have asked/paid for a static ip from your provider, it may change at some arbitrary time in the future. If you don't have access to the modem, you need to ask the sys admin who maintians it.

Comment: This could vary depending on the setup. If the 'modem' and router are separate (as mine are), then the router is where you'd look.

Comment: This is correct. Don't know why I presumed a dual unit. I have had both in the past.